# adding library to symfony projects

Tags: symfony, shared-libraries

I create symfony projects via composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"6.3.*" my_project, then create a library called shared adding composer.json. the idea is for my library to provide common code for my_project

composer.json my_project

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,  
  "require": {
        "shared/library": "dev-main" <- my library
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
          "type": "path",
          "url": "../../Shared/"
        }
      ],
}
```

composer.json shared library

```
{
    "name": "shared/library",
    "description": "Shared code between microservices",
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "Shared\\": "/"
      }
    }
  }
```

and now to use common library register class from library to services.yaml in this case registration classes are used for message Bus

services.yaml

```
Shared\:
    resource: "../../../Shared/"
  _instanceof:
        Shared\Application\Command\CommandHandlerInterface:
          public: true
          tags:
            - { name: messenger.message_handler, bus: messenger.bus.command }

        Shared\Application\Query\QueryHandlerInterface:
          public: true
          tags:
            - { name: messenger.message_handler, bus: messenger.bus.query }
```

right now i got error :

```
**#message: "Compile Error: Cannot declare class Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader, because the name is already in use"**
```

Comment: I have not tried using `composer create-project` for a symfony project in quite some time.  The recommended way to create a symfony project is to use the symfony CLI.  You might start over and give it a shot.

Comment: remove Shared\: and resource line - they are not needed. just declare the _instanceOf as you would with another namespace. Composer already nows how to load them. of course. autoconfigure of services in this namespace will never work. But thats by intent.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need the resource loader for this.

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    _instanceof:
        # services whose classes are instances of CustomInterface will be tagged automatically
        Cwd\TablerBundle\Menu\HasMenuInterface:
            tags: ['tabler.menu_item']
        Cwd\SearchBundle\SearchableInterface:
            tags: ['cwd.searchable']
```

InstanceOf is enough. I use this all the time.